# dotnet bundle fails when multiple csproj files present

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm using the dotnet bundle VS extension, which works fine when I only have one csproj in my project folder, I recently added another csproj (for other reasons) and now the bundler fails with error

```
Specify which project file to use because this '[project folder]' contains more than one project file.
```

Is there a way to specify the csproj? The bundle command is declared in the csproj as follows:

```
  <Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <Exec Command="dotnet bundle" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: I've just switched to using Gulp bundling for this